# How to apply a composition on a 3d object in adobe after effects

Tags: 3d, after-effects

i want to create something like this
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJ7E7uEZN00&feature=player_embedded

can i create a composition and use it as a texture on a 3d object in after effects??

if not any other software which can help

---

we can render video as a texture in 3ds max.
so we create the video effect in after affect and use it as a texture on the model in 3ds max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that was projection mapped, meaning what you are seeing in the video is actually what the audience's eyes see in real life.  Those textures/animations were created and then actually projected onto the car in real life, these effects were not done in post.

However, if you want to create something like this, I believe you're probably going to have better luck using a true 3D application, [Autodesk Maya](http://usa.autodesk.com/maya/) or [3ds Max](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/) come to mind, as well as [Maxon Cinema4D](http://www.maxon.net/) or my personal favorite [Blender](http://blender.org), whichever suits your taste.

If you're going to have any shots with any camera movement, you're going to want a 3D motion tracker like PFTrack or PHoe, but as of GSoC 2011, Blender has a motion tracker built in, I believe it will be in trunk soon.

I think the process would involve modeling your subject and texturing it, tracking the camera moves, and compositing it with your original footage.  After Effects could be helpful for compositing your 3D render, but I don't think it's the right tool for the job in this case.